# PhpStorm Coding Style: align anonymous function

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am currently trying to use the PEAR Coding Standards and I can't get anonymous functions to align correctly in function calls. Here is an example :

What is recommended by the standards:

```
test(
    function () {
        return "";
    }
);
```

This works by default.

However, as soon as I have more than one parameter, PhpStorm unindents the function content and closing brace :

```
test(
    "test", function () {
return "";
}
);
```

But what is recommended by the standards is the following :

```
test(
    "test", function () {
        return "";
    }
);
```

Note: 
When enabling "Function declaration parameters" > "Align when multiline", I have the correct alignment if I put each parameter on its own line :

```
test(
    "test", 
    function () {
        return "";
    }
);
```

I couldn't find a way to make this possible without having to put each parameter on its own line, would someone if this is possible/how to do it ?

Note 2 : I loaded the PEAR Coding Style using the "Predefined Style" already implemented out of the box in PhpStorm and only did little tweaks.

Note 3 : I am using PHPCS to check my code. Here are the errors I get with the PhpStorm-formatted code :

4 | ERROR | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 8 spaces, found 4 (PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent.Incorrect)

5 | ERROR | [x] Line indented incorrectly; expected 4 spaces, found 0 (PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent.IncorrectExact)

5 | ERROR | [x] Multi-line function call not indented correctly; expected 4 spaces but found 0
   |       |     (PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature.Indent)

5 | ERROR | [x] Closing brace indented incorrectly; expected 4 spaces, found 0 (PEAR.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.Indent)

Line 4 is the line where the `return "";` is.

Comment: Could you link the coding standards you're referring to? I've looked at https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php and can't find a part about anonymous functions.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't read the standards thoroughly. I am using PHPCS which checks that I am following the PEAR standards. (This post is therefore more about being able to indent anonymous functions regarding to the start of the `function` keyword.) I updated the post to include the errors I get from PHPCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no setting to adjust for that case. It looks like a bug similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32914, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25700 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35221. Feel free to add a comment with your example at e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32914 or submit your own bug report

Comment: Thank you for showing these to me. It is exactly the case `anonymous function structures` in the first link. These posts were posted years ago, I'm guessing they have more urgent matters at hand.